# multiplying two columns, different tables... one column null

Tags: mysql, sql

In this join query, i am multiplying two columns from different tables, `premium` & `points`. What i want to happen is if there are no columns joined in the `premium` table then the multiplier will be 1.

here is the query

```
 SELECT parent.*,(premiumtable.bid * pointstable.points) as total FROM strings parent
        LEFT JOIN premium premiumtable on parent.sid=premiumtable.sid AND premiumtable.paid='1'
        LEFT JOIN points pointstable on parent.sid=pointstable.`string-id`
        WHERE parent.category=:category AND (parent.submittype='0' OR parent.submittype='3') GROUP BY parent.id ORDER BY total LIMIT 5
```

So if nothing is joined on the `premiumtable` instead of `premiumtable.bid * pointstable.points` it would be `1 * pointstable.points`.  The `premiumtable.bid` acts as a multiplier, if it isn't present, i'd want `total` to equal `pointstable.points`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT   parent.*,
         (COALESCE(premiumtable.bid,1) * pointstable.points) as total 
FROM strings parent
LEFT JOIN premium premiumtable 
   on parent.sid=premiumtable.sid AND premiumtable.paid='1'
LEFT JOIN points pointstable 
   on parent.sid=pointstable.`string-id`
WHERE parent.category=:category 
AND (parent.submittype='0' OR parent.submittype='3') 
GROUP BY parent.id 
ORDER BY total LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT parent.*,
       case when premiumtable.bid is null
            then pointstable.points
            else premiumtable.bid * pointstable.points
       end as total 
FROM strings parent
LEFT JOIN premium premiumtable on parent.sid=premiumtable.sid AND premiumtable.paid='1'
LEFT JOIN points pointstable on parent.sid=pointstable.`string-id`
WHERE parent.category=:category
AND (parent.submittype='0' OR parent.submittype='3')
GROUP BY parent.id
ORDER BY total
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Everyone who has programmed in any programming language can understand the syntax for `CASE`.  Everyone who has ever run across `COALESCE` has  been forced to lookup the meaning and syntax.  How about `ISNULL`, which could also be understood?